# Solr spatial query returning location outside the search range

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 5.3.0 and evaluating geo spatial search. I followed the instructions per online reference and see results outside the radius. Do you see any issue in the schema or data?

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo2/select?q=*.*&wt=json&indent=true&spatial=true&pt=4.89%2C-4.05&sfield=geoloc&d=1


<schema name="weather lookup index" version="1.3">
<types>
 <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
 <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
 <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
 <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
</types>

<fields>
 <field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
 <field name="geoloc" type="location" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="true"/>
 <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
</fields>

<defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "responseHeader": { 
        "status": 0, 
        "QTime": 2, 
        "params": { 
            "q": ".", 
            "pt": "4.89,-4.05", 
            "d": "1", 
            "indent": "true", 
            "spatial": "true", 
            "sfield": "geoloc", 
            "wt": "json", 
            "": "1443653671468" 
        } 
    }, 
    "response": { 
        "numFound": 1, 
        "start": 0, 
        "docs": [ 
            { 
                "name": [ "test" ], 
                "geoloc": [ "40.89,-86.05" ], 
                "id": "9711c69e-9ac3-4302-a41d-719f57fde24c",
                "_version": 1513779446777118700
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the result I got: {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 2,
    "params": {
      "q": "*.*",
      "pt": "4.89,-4.05",
      "d": "1",
      "indent": "true",
      "spatial": "true",
      "sfield": "geoloc",
      "wt": "json",
      "_": "1443653671468"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "name": [
          "test"
        ],
        "geoloc": [
          "40.89,-86.05"
        ],
        "id": "9711c69e-9ac3-4302-a41d-719f57fde24c",
        "_version_": 1513779446777118700
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: you should add the response into the question instead of separately in the comment.

Comment: You should at least use the most recent version number for your schema, depending on which version of Solr you're using. LatLonTypes couldn't be multiValued pre-4.0 (schema version <1.4 IIRC).

Comment: Changed schema version to 5.3 and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you want to add a filter to your search as documented [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch). As you have it now you are defining parameters, but not filtering anything.

```
&fq={!geofilt pt=4.89,-4.05 sfield=geoloc d=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looked like Solr didn't index lat long all along. Solr creates a file called managed_schema in C:\Program Files\solr\server\solr\\conf that override my schema.xml. I got rid of the managed_schema file and it started using schema.xml (I had to add few missing types to schema.xml to make it work).